# The verb agreement for "one" when used as a subject

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number

The first sentence in "Blake" in *The Sacred Wood* by T. S. Eliot is

> If one follow Blake’s mind through the several stages of his poetic
>   development it is impossible to regard him as a naïf, a wild man, a
>   wild pet for the supercultivated.

[full article](http://www.bartleby.com/200/sw13.html)

Why did he use "follow", but not "follows"? Because this book has been reprinted for several times, the usage of "follow" here is not likely to be a typo.

**EDIT:** 
In *Selected Essays, 1917-1932*, Eliot changed "follow" to "follows".

Comment: Either *follow* was an irregular verb back then or it's a mistake. I'm going for miftake.

Comment: I think it's a rather odd use of a subjunctive-type verb after *if*, and deliberate. That doesn't make it right, though.

Comment: Although there is a big difference between *if one follow* and *if one follows*, but the former is still in wide use. http://www.google.com/search?q=%22if%20one%20follow%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en

Comment: Ain't it possible that "follow" was used because "Blake's mind" was alternatively used for "Blake's thoughts"(plural)?

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr: So the verb takes the number of its object? That's rather more unlikely than the subjunctive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this to be a pedantic application of the [subjunctive mood](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-subjunctive.htm) following *if*.

*If* in the quote introduces something which Eliot
 -     wants to happen
 -     hopes will happen or
 -     imagines happening
and Eliot has used the subjunctive form of *follow*.

Comment: Coming after an *if*, wouldn't the subjunctive be a past subjunctive *followed*?

Comment: The form of the present and past subjunctive is the same for every verb except *to be*. See the reference.

Comment: It should be a present subjunctive anyway, because the verb in the main clause is "is". I can't imagine using "follow" with "was" here, although I suppose it might have once been correct.

Comment: @Andrew Leach ~ I did look at that, but it is contradicted by [this reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive) that gives 'if I owned' as a past subjunctive, and [this one](http://www.wordpower.ws/grammar/gramch09.html) that gives 'worked' as a past subjunctive.

Comment: @Roaring Fish: There seems to be little point in speaking of past subjunctive forms when they are indistinguishable from past tense forms. That's what Bas Aarts thinks, anyway, in his Oxford Modern English Grammar: http://www.amazon.com/Oxford-Modern-English-Grammar-Aarts/dp/0199533199/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1341412991&sr=1-1&keywords=oxford+modern+english+grammar+aarts+2011

Comment: http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=4049